# Работа с формами js

Tags: javascript

У меня есть форма. которая добавляет в контейнер фоном изображение ,когда я ввожу туда ссылку на это изображение. но помимо изображения еще туда добавляется ссылка как текст. как сделать так,что бы текст не добавлялся поверх фотки.

```
    const containers = document.querySelector('.p-list'); // div куда добавляется карточка

    function newCard(nameValue, linkValue) {
  const container = document.createElement('div'); //карточка
  container.classList.add('p-card');

  const imgLink = document.createElement('div');  //cсылка
  const imgName = document.createElement('h3');   //заголовок

  imgLink.classList.add('card__image');
  imgLink.textContent = linkValue; 

  imgName.classList.add('card__name');
  imgName.textContent = nameValue;

  container.appendChild(imgLink);
  container.appendChild(imgName);

  return container;
}

function addCard(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const name = form.elements.name;
  const link = form.elements.link;

  const container = newCard(name.value, link.value);
  containers.appendChild(container);

  container.querySelector('.card__image').setAttribute('style', `background-image: url(${link.value})`);
  name.value = '';
  link.value = '';

}
```

Comment: Надо дополнить код, так не совсем понятно. Вы говорите container.querySelector('.card__image').....
но он ещё в этот момент пустой, а значит найти вы там ничего не можете. 
Дополните код, покажите его вместе с HTML полностью и мы постараемся вам помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и не понял чего вы хотели, но попробуйте вот так.

```
   function newCard(nameValue, linkValue) {
    const container = document.createElement('div'); //карточка
    container.classList.add('p-card');

    const imgLink = document.createElement('div');  //cсылка
    const imgName = document.createElement('h3');   //заголовок

    imgLink.classList.add('card__image');

    imgName.classList.add('card__name');
    imgName.textContent = nameValue;

    container.appendChild(imgLink);
    container.appendChild(imgName);

    return container;
  }

  function addCard(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const name = form.elements.name;
    const link = form.elements.link;

    const container = newCard(name.value, link.value);
    containers.appendChild(container);

    container.querySelector('.card__image').setAttribute('style', `background-image: url(${link.value})`);
    name.value = '';
    link.value = '';

  }
```

Comment: смотрите. есть форма. в ней 2 поля. в одном я ввожу названия картинки. в другом ссылку на нее. и значение поля ссылки делаю фоном контейнера, который создает эта форма. но поверх картинки остается текст того,что я ввел в поле номер2(то есть остается ссылка поверх каритнки)

Comment: Вставьте код из ответа вместо своего, текст теперь будет оставаться только в теге H3
Если у вас скрипт в отдельном файле JS то для обновления страницы жмите ctrl+F5, чтобы сбрасывать кеш браузера.